# DataGridView with listbox column

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have some columns with long text of numbers separated by commas
I want to show the `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn` as `ListBox` when it is clicked
how can i do it?
Desirably without inheritance.

Comment: it's ok. i added a listbox to the datagrid and set it's visibility in the grid CellContentClick event. with datagrid GetCellDisplayRectangle method i set the listbox Location property to the rectangle Location

Comment: Using the answer below, you don't need to show a listbox above grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can show a multi-line text in `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn` and make the row to be auto-size using designer or code this way:

- Set [`AutoSizeRowMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.autosizerowsmode(v=vs.110).aspx) property of your `DataGridView` to `AllCells`
- Set the [`DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellstyle.wrapmode(v=vs.110).aspx) property of your `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn` to `True`

So it's enough to convert those comma-separated numbers to a `Environment.NewLine` separated text and show them in `DataGridView`.

[image]

Comment: great solution but i'll use the listbox showing on click